# Insertar datos de una tabla dinámica en HTML a MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, insert, html-tabla

Muchas gracias por pararse un minuto. Estoy generando una tabla con productos para ser colocados como una única entrada en la base datos, donde se introducen los productos a través de un formulario y luego con otra función se toman los productos  de la tabla y se colocan en una tabla en la base de datos.

Todo está bien con la creación de la tabla pero no encuentro porque no me hace el registro en la base de datos.

```js
  var i=1;
function myCreateFunction() {
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var fecha = document.getElementById("Fecha").value;
  var Cantidad = document.getElementById("Cantidad").value;
  var Descripcion = document.getElementById("Descripcion").value;
  var Ficha = document.getElementById("Ficha").value;
  var modulo = document.getElementById("modulo").value;
  var nodocu = document.getElementById("no_docu").value;
  
  var row = table.insertRow(-1);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
  var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
  var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
  
  
  cell1.innerHTML = fecha;
  cell2.innerHTML = Cantidad;
  cell3.innerHTML = Descripcion;
  cell4.innerHTML = Ficha;
  cell5.innerHTML = modulo;
  cell6.innerHTML = nodocu;
  
  
  i++;
  
}

function myDeleteFunction() {
  var rows = document.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName("tr").length;
  if (rows>1){
  r = confirm("¿Desea eliminar este producto?")
  if (r == true) {
    document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(-1);
} 
}
}

function tabla() {
var tRows = [];
tab = document.getElementById('myTable');
arreglo = ["f2","qty","des1","fic1","dest1","sal1"]
for (var r = 1; r < tab.rows.length; r++) {
  var tRow = [];// start new row array
  for (var c = 0; c < tab.rows[r].cells.length; c++) {
    tRow[c] = tab.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML;
    document.getElementById(arreglo[c]).innerHTML = tRow[c];
  }
  tRows.push(tRow);
}

console.log(tRows);

document.getElementById('formu').submit();


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="css/mdb.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.8.3/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
   
  
    
    
    <title>Registro de Productos</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
            <div class="col">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">DRF</a>
              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                <div class="navbar-nav">
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="sysdrif.php">Consulta de Registros<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="regdrif.php">Entrada de Registros</a>
                  
                </div>
              </div>
            </nav>
</div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
            <br><br><br>
                
                <h2>Registro de Productos</h2>
            </div>
            </div > 
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4"><h5>Entrada de Registros<h5> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 offset-5">
            <button onclick="tabla()" class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded justify-center enviar" >Enviar<i class="fas fa-arrow-right ml-1"></i></button> 
            <br>
          
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              
              <div class="col-9 card" style="padding: 1.5em">
              <div class="table-wrapper-scroll-y my-custom-scrollbar">
              <table class="table table-bordered mb-0" id="myTable">
                  <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <td><b><h5>Fecha</b></td>
                        <td><b><h5>Cantidad</b></td>
                        <td><b><h5>Descripción</b></td>
                        <td><b><h5>Ficha</b></td>
                        <td><b><h5>Destino</b></td>
                        <td><b><h5># de Salida</b></td>
                        
                      </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>

                  </tbody>
                
                            
                </table>
                </div>
                <button onclick="myDeleteFunction()" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-rounded"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i>  Eliminar</button>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body card">
              
              
              <form method="POST">
                <i>Fecha:</i> <br>
                <input type="date" id="Fecha" required><br>
                <i>Cantidad:</i><br>
                <input type="number" id="Cantidad" required><br>
                <i>Descripción:</i><br>
                <input type="Text" id="Descripcion" required><br>
                <i>Ficha:</i><br>
                <input type="text" id="Ficha" required><br>
                <i>Destino:</i><br>
                <select name="modulo" id="modulo" required>
                  <option value="C-1">C-1</option>
                  <option value="C-2">C-2</option>
                  <option value="C-4">C-4</option>
                  <option value="C-5">C-5</option>
                  <option value="Santiago">Santiago</option>
                </select> <br>
                <i># de Salida:</i><br>
                <input type="text" id="no_docu" required>
              </form>
              <br>
              <button onclick="myCreateFunction()" class="btn btn-success btn-block rounded"> <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>  Insertar</button>  
              </div>
            
            </div>
            <p id="info"></p>
            <form  action="regdrif.php" method="POST" id="formu" >
            <input hidden type="text" id="f2">
            <input hidden type="text" id="qty">
            <input hidden type="text" id="des1">
            <input hidden type="text" id="fic1">
            <input hidden type="text" id="dest1">
            <input hidden type="text" id="sal1">
            </form>
</div>

<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$databasename = "sysdrif_db";
$ficha=0;
$fi="";
$ff="";
                    
$connect= mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databasename);
if ($connect->connect_error) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . $connect->connect_error);
  }
 if( isset($_POST['f2']) ) { 
  $fec=($_POST['f2']);
  $cant=($_POST['qty']);
  $descr=($_POST['desc1']);
  $fich=($_POST['fich1']);
  $destin=($_POST['dest1']);
  $nodoc=($_POST['sal1']);

  $query=("INSERT INTO movreg (Fecha, Cantidad, Descripcion, Ficha, Destino, no_docu) VALUES (".$fec.",".$cant.",".$descr.",".$fich.",".$destin.",".$nodoc).")";
  $result1 = mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die(mysqli_error($query));
  echo $query;
  
  }
?>


<!-- SCRIPTS -->
<!-- JQuery -->
<!-- JQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.4/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.8.3/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 // Material Select Initialization
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('.mdb-select').material_select();
 });
 </script>

  
</body>
</html>
```

Como pueden ver, lo que se busca es hacer una lista para luego que esta lista se introduzca en la base de datos. Esto como medida para garantizar que no sean tocados los registros. En la parte que mas requiero de su ayuda es en confirmar si los datos están siendo enviados y que se introduzcan de manera correcta en al db

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el error esta en la función tabla:

```
document.getElementById(arreglo[c]).innerHTML = tRow[c];
```

Estas cambiando el código html en lugar del valor del input, que es el que extrae $_GET y $_POST, evitando pasar de if( isset($_POST['f2']) ) ya que no tiene valor.

El cambio sería:

```
document.getElementById(arreglo[c]).value = tRow[c];
```